# google analytics api - mcf api - assistedConversions - How to get only e-commerce conversions?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Hello Analytics API users!

Is there a Way to get or to filter the totals to get only one type of conversions - e-commerce conversions?

Example from the docs:

**mcf:assistedConversions**

The number of conversions for which this channel appeared on the conversion path, but was not the final conversion interaction. This metric includes **both goal completions and transactions**.

All the metrics have both conversion types. Is there a way to get only e-commerce totals? How you deal with this problem?

Comment: Wouldn't filtering by "mcf:conversionType equals Transaction" work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to narrow down your API report to eCommerce transactions.

You need to set up a filter for `mcd:converionType` to equal `Transaction`.

An example in PHP would look like this:

```
$optParams = array('dimensions' => 'mcf:medium',
                   'filters' => 'mcf:conversionType%3D%3DTransaction');

$ga_result = $analytics->data_mcf->get('ga:'.$profileID,
                                       '2016-08-01',
                                       '2016-08-31,
                                       'mcf:assistedConversions,mcf:lastInteractionConversions',
                                       $optParams);
```

Further details are available [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/dimsmets/conversionpaths#mcf:conversionType).

Comment: Can I ask you why you use %3D%3D insted of ==

Comment: I've taken it from API documentation. Here is a description of filter operators and their usage, which works for me in practice: [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters)